# AWS Code Deploy Deployment Failed for shell scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Am trying to create CodeDeploy Deployment Group using the Cloud Formation Stack. Every time I run the stack, am getting script errors like Bad Interpreter, rm/ll command not found, /r /n errors. I tried to change the shell script files using dos2unix and zip those files and upload to CodeDeploy but no success.

Following is the error statement I get in logs:

```
2018-09-01 10:41:45 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2681)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.037239 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":4,\"script_name\":\"BeforeInstall.sh\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: BeforeInstall.sh run as user root failed with exit code 127\",\"log\":\"LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall\\nScript - BeforeInstall.sh\\n[stderr]/usr/bin/env: bash\\r: No such file or directory\\n\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTEvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OTkzNzM1NTM2Nzc4OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC05V0kzWk5DNlYiLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OTkzNzM1NTM2Nzc4Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDk1NGJlNjk4OTMzMzY5MjgiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkJlZm9yZUluc3RhbGwiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjMsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")

2018-09-01 10:41:45 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2681)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script at specified location: BeforeInstall.sh run as user root failed with exit code 127 - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:173:in `execute_script'

......
......

2018-09-01 10:41:45 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2681)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.018288 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":5,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: BeforeInstall.sh run as user root failed with exit code 127\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"WyJjb20uYW1hem9uLmFwb2xsby5kZXBsb3ljb250cm9sLmRvbWFpbi5Ib3N0Q29tbWFuZElkZW50aWZpZXIiLHsiZGVwbG95bWVudElkIjoiQ29kZURlcGxveS91cy1lYXN0LTEvUHJvZC9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OTkzNzM1NTM2Nzc4OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC05V0kzWk5DNlYiLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6OTkzNzM1NTM2Nzc4Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDk1NGJlNjk4OTMzMzY5MjgiLCJjb21tYW5kTmFtZSI6IkJlZm9yZUluc3RhbGwiLCJjb21tYW5kUG9zaXRpb24iOjMsImNvbW1hbmRBdHRlbXB0IjoxfV0=")
```

What can be the possible reason for failing?

Answer (score 0):

The logs indicate that there is some problem with your scripts, specifically `BeforeInstall.sh`. Something in that script is failing with an exit code of 127. I would recommend adding logs to that script to see where it's actually failing. Once you identify the command that's failing, you can see what exit code 127 means for that particular command.

If you want help debugging that particular script, you should open up another question and provide the script, including the logs when it's gets run.

**A note of CodeDeploy lifecycle hooks**

In your case, your `BeforeInstall` script is failing, which will be the script that gets deployed with your application. However, if had been your `ApplicationStop` script that was failing, it's important to understand that `ApplicationStop` uses scripts from the last successful deployment, so if the last successful deployment had a fault script, it can cause future deployments to fail until [these steps are followed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-deployments-lifecycle-event-failures).